# how to set gerrit change action icon

Tags: gerrit

I have met to extent gerrit3.2
I want to set a icon to my changeAction,but I don't know what icon name is.Gerrit docs simple gives changeActions.setIcon(key, icon),icon: The name of the icon.How can I get the name?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the code of gerrit - the 'icon' parameter is using a SVG def from polygerrit-ui/app/elements/shared/gr-icons/gr-icons.ts

The 'icon' is the id from one of the def from that file. By using 'robot' for example, the SVG def for the robot SVG shape is used for the UI.